# How does the classpath influence the *.class file

Tags: java, classpath

I have some source code files that I want to compile. For that, I have to specify a classpath which contains (by means of specifying the jars) all used classes and methods with the correct signatures.

Assume I have two different classpaths which both lead to a compilation without errors. These classpaths may differ in the order of the jars, the version of the jars (e.g. an older version of commons collections is replaced by a newer one) or by the presence of unnecessary jars.

How can these classpaths influence the byte code? I read that the order of the constant pool might be different for different classpaths. Are there other possible differences?

Again: I assume that all dependencies for compilation are satisfied, but maybe with different jars.

Comment: AFAIK they wouldn't influence the byte code at all. When the byte code is *run* the classpath matters because of load order. All the byte code has is FQNs the loader tries to resolve from the *runtime* classpath.

Comment: @DaveNewton what if your code has some expression like `double x = 1.0 + LibraryClass.LIBRARY_CONSTANT;`. And let's say that one version of `LibraryClass` defines `LIBRARY_CONSTANT` as an `int` but a different version defines it as a `double`? Wouldn't the cast operation yield diffrerent byte code? Or is that a runtime thing as well?

Comment: @MadPhysicist It would be different bytecode iff it's a final static constant initialized in its declaration, e.g., if it's initialized in a static block, or initialized with a non-constant initializer, then no.

Comment: @DaveNewton. So there technically is a case where the classpath may affect the compilation :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, I'm agreeing with you?

Answer (score 1):

The classes you compile with do affect your produced bytecode.  Areas that I know are affected:

- `static` the code for looking up and calling a static method is different than the code for regular (instance) methods; this can cause your code to fail at run time if it is run with an incompatible version of a library
- constants: many constants (integers, strings, etc.) are inlined by the compiler if they are declared as `static` and `final` to a constant value outside of a `static` block; if the different versions of the dependent libraries define different values or types for constants that are referenced by your code, then your code will have a different value in its bytecode

Comment: Declaring `static final` is not sufficient, they must also be (a) initialized with constant values, and (b) not initialized in a static block.

Comment: And what about the order of the constant pool (see my question)? Can it be influenced by the claspath or not?

Comment: Constants are, essentially by definition, `static` and `final`.  If it is not `final` then it is variable rather than constant.  It doesn't hurt to explicitly note those modifier keywords.

Comment: @JFMeier I don't know about the order of the constant pool.  I have never concerned myself with that since I neither write compilers nor VMs.  I imagine that the order may vary by compiler.